# Upgrade Next 12 to 13 and React 17 to 18 - issue with Github build Deploy Next.js app - The root value has an unexpected property, target,

Tags: next.js

Github build failed:
- name: Deploy Next.js app
run: npx serverless@2.72.2

aNA
error:
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: node_modules/.bin/next build
warn  - Invalid next.config.js options detected:

- The root value has an unexpected property, target, which is not in the list of allowed properties (amp, analyticsId, assetPrefix, basePath, cleanDistDir, compiler, compress, crossOrigin, devIndicators, distDir, env, eslint, excludeDefaultMomentLocales, experimental, exportPathMap, generateBuildId, generateEtags, headers, httpAgentOptions, i18n, images, modularizeImports, onDemandEntries, optimizeFonts, output, outputFileTracing, pageExtensions, poweredByHeader, productionBrowserSourceMaps, publicRuntimeConfig, reactStrictMode, redirects, rewrites, sassOptions, serverRuntimeConfig, skipMiddlewareUrlNormalize, skipTrailingSlashRedirect, staticPageGenerationTimeout, swcMinify, trailingSlash, transpilePackages, typescript, useFileSystemPublicRoutes, webpack).

### next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const headers = async () => {
    return [
        {
            source: '/:path*',
            headers: [
                {
                    key: 'X-Content-Type-Options',
                    value: 'nosniff'
                },
                {
                    key: 'X-Frame-Options',
                    value: 'SAMEORIGIN'
                },

            ]
        }
    ]

}
const nextConfig = {
reactStrictMode: true,
output: 'standalone',
transpilePackages: \['@ionic/react', '@ionic/core', '@stencil/core', 'ionicons'\],
async redirects() {
return \[
 {
    source: '/',
    destination: '/language',
    permanent: true
 }
\]
},
headers,
  images: {
    domains: \['media.graphcms.com', 'res.cloudinary.com', 
   'images.unsplash.com', 'media.graphassets.com'\],
  unoptimized: true,
}
};
module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Can anyone advice how to resolve this issue? trying to fix/rewrite all day and no luck... In case, local terminal: npm run build is passed.